# Some trouble with horizontal navigation drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to code a site layout which is basically just organized as such:

```
Header (only an image)
Horizontal Nav
Content
```

At first, my idea was to just have a container div and have header, nav, and content as a div inside the container; however, I ran into some troubles doing the navigation. I want it to be a horizontal navigation, so I just made a list, and used inline to make it across. I ran into problems when I started trying to incorporate a drop down list of secondary links. This is the first time coding anything since 2009 so I am actually kind of just learning new stuff. I tried a bunch of different things on Google, but I don't understand their explanation.

Should I use the nav tag for my list within the div? Here is the jsfiddle base code I have been using to try and figure out: http://jsfiddle.net/mcpy/z8yvx/110/

Comment: So you want the menu to be vertical or horizontal?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but here is a better starting point - since you haven't been writing html for 5 years: This might help you get up to date:  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/u25gn/

Comment: Here is a pretty hard-core dropdown menu:  http://codepen.io/catalinred/pen/ngBJF

Answer (score 0):

So why you can't use bootstrap ? it's very easy to use and you can get drop down menu in bootstrap.

For example script dropdown in bootstrap :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and you can see and learn in [Boostrap Dropdown Menu](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns).

Comment: Maybe because I did not know about bootstrap until now. I'll give it a look, thanks.